# Ubuntu 19.10. freezes again on startup

Tags: boot, kernel, freeze

Some days ago I had trouble with my laptop. It stopped working and froze on the Ubunu splash. Mostly, before the first white bubble turned orange. I've played around a lot since i thought it might be due to the graphics card. Nomodeset, no-splash, nothing worked.

Then I remembered that the Kernel was updated. I switched grub from Linux 5.3.0-23-generic to Linux 5.3.0-22-generic. Yey, it just worked again! I deleted the newer Kernel and it worked flawlessly. For some days. Today morning, I just got the same freeze mechanism right on splash screen. I didn't do any update since then.

Nomodeset or no-splash don't help, it just freezes in an empty, purple screen then. Changing to 5.3.0-18-generic brings me to a black screen with the iconic, white underdash and after some minutes I got the gdm login, but it all was very slow, animations stutter, it takes a while until the window pops up when launching something.

Any help? pls? :(